# Search product websites without api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

Sorry for the bad title and description, but I was wondering if there is anyway I could search/list products from other sites (say Express, American Eagle), from a web app I create, even if the site doesn't have an API.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  How do you think Google and every other search engine does it?  They just spider the sites and index the contents.  The devil, of course, is in the details.  But it's certainly possible to do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. Unless you want only to fetch some data from a certain HTML page, then you need to use some regular expressions. But searching the database is not possible if you don't have the ability to connect to it directly or via some APIs.

Comment: Regular expressions aren't the right way to pull data from a web page.